AWS Java SDK Cognito User Authentication Flows
After hours of research and no answer I have come here to ask. I want to build a user flow for a full stack application in AWS where I am using the CDK; I want to be able to authenticate users based on their email/username and password as well as know what user group within the cognito user pool they are part of. How can I do this? My serverside code is in Java.
I've tried to look into documentation, which has yielded no clear answer.
